# Hyundai Santro difficulty in cranking when engine is Hot

Tags: santro

I have a 2002 hyundai santro. Theresis no issue with cold start. Car starts fine. But when the engine is hot or after a drive of 30 minutes, car tries to crank with difficulty like an underpowered battery. If i wait for 10-20 minutes, car starts without any difficulty.

Battery seems to be fine. Displays 12.4 volt
Alternater also seems to be fine. 13.9 - 14.2 volt measures when engine is on
Starter motor armature, brushes, soleinoid and Battery cables changed. Checked the engine earth and that also fine.
Coolant temperature was changed, as it was not performing well.
When hot, temperature reading lies betweenupper and lower limit, and seems to be fine.

Please advice why i am facing this issue.

Comment: check the voltage drop on the starter b+ cable and do the same for the engine to b- and post your results.

Comment: When cold start, voltage drops to around 10.4 volt and when hot start,voltage drops to around 1 volt.

Hope this is what you are looking for. If not please advice.